# Bootstrap validate on html appended element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have defined elements like below and added an custom logic to add more elements on click of + button on input control-'EngVDCategory'.

```
  <div class="VDGroup">
              <div class="VDGroupPlaceHolder">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Engineering and Vendor data</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                       <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" id="EngVDCategory" name="EngVDCategory" placeholder="Engineering and Vendor data" class="form-control">
                          <span class="input-group-addon cursor" id='addButton'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "  ></i></span>
                          <span class="input-group-addon cursor" id='removeButton'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></i></span>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

[On click of + new element is added below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgESy.png)

I also have validators initialized under $(document).ready(function()

$('#filterForm').bootstrapValidator({

```
        fields: {
            EngVDCategory: {
                validators: {

                        stringLength: {
                            min: 10,
                            max: 100,
                            message: 'The name must be more than 10 and less than 100 characters long'
                        }

                }
            },
                        EngVDCategory2: {
                validators: {

                        stringLength: {
                            min: 10,
                            max: 100,
                            message: 'The name must be more than 10 and less than 100 characters long'
                        }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

On click of submit I would like to validate both elements EngVDCategory and newly added html element EngVDCategory2 as well. But it validates only EngVDCategory element. How to validate the new elements as well ?

[validation doesn't work for appended element -'EngVDCategory2 '.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5wLE.png)

Here is my logic to append

```
$("#addButton").click(function () {
                      if( ($('.VDGroup .VDGroupPlaceHolder').length+1) > 5) {
                          alert("Only maximum of 5 Categories are allowed");
                          return false;
                      }
                      var id = ($('.VDGroup .VDGroupPlaceHolder').length + 1).toString();
                      $('.VDGroup').append('<div class="VDGroupPlaceHolder"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label">Engineering and Vendor data</label><div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer"><input type="text" id="EngVDCategory' + id + '" name="EngVDCategory' + id + '" placeholder="Engineering and Vendor data ' + id + '" class="form-control" ></div></div></div>');
                     // validator.addField($(this));
                  });
```